# The list of iPhone questions is in a chaotic order

Tags: bug, tags, questions

Viewing the [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) tag by newest shows the questions in a chaotic order. For example, there are large gaps between the posted dates on questions, despite there being questions posted in between:

[image: question list with large gap]

On the next page of results, the questions go back to being posted "x hours ago", even though they are clearly newer than the ones posted on 2009.

Comment: What are we supposed to look at there? The ordering seems just fine?

Comment: @Bart look it now

Comment: And you are on the "newest" tab?

Comment: @Bart of course you can see it by yourself now

Comment: Well, I don't see what you're seeing over here. So no-repro for me.

Comment: @Bart weird,i can see it at the end of first page and second page

Comment: Are you looking under the "Relevance" tab? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5biphone%5d%20crash) seems properly ordered.

Comment: @Jack no,just nomal page of iphone tag,oh god,all of you can't see it ?what happen to my computer....

Comment: What do you mean, "normal page?" Also, if you think this is a problem with your computer maybe you shouldn't be using Stack Overflow... :O

Comment: @Jack my per page show 50 questions

Comment: **That has nothing to do with this!** Which tab are you on?

Comment: @Doorknob see the picture i get

Comment: um... that's what it's supposed to do

Comment: For what it's worth, I **am** able to reproduce this on later pages, like [page six](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone?page=6&sort=newest&pagesize=30). I imagine it'll likely magically clear itself up, but this isn't the first time this has happened.

Comment: @Mac they are the same quetion,i found once before and it's appear now

Comment: This is all cached and sometimes the cache get mixed up. Nothing fatal here, unless it happens in all tags or for longer than few hours.